# Dotnet 5 Kubernetes TLS fails in production

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, kubernetes, .net-core

I've been running my dotnet 3 app okay in prod using self-signed certificate but after upgrading to dotnet 5 kestrel fails to start up with the below error. My server certificate is signed by an intermediate CA which is also included in the Kubernetes pod. Could use an extra set of eye.

This is my StartUp.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                    {
                        var config = context.Configuration;
                        certificate = new X509Certificate2(config["CERT"], config["PASS"]);


                        Log.Information($"found certificate {certificate.Subject}");
                        serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.ServerCertificate = certificate;
                        });
                    });
                });
```

And this is the error from I'm getting on pod startup.

```
[41m[1m[37mcrit[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainElementCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainElementCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at ABC.Auth.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/ABC.Auth.Web/Program.cs:line 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I had to add the CA certificate (crt) in the pod, the intermediate certificate was not enough to satisfy the certificate chain. Hopes it helps someone else getting the above excepton.